# MySql Resultset Stream large complex query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've been trying to figure out if MySql's ResultSet Streaming works on complex queries. I have use MySql's ResultSet streaming via

`statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    // Simple select * from my table, streaming works great
            rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from my_table");`

which works fine when the query is just "select * from my_table". But I have notice that if my query isn't just a simple "select * from my_table", the streaming approach does not work. When I debug my application (Java), I notice that using a simple query the result comes back fast. When I switch it to use a more complex query, it just hangs (Well, I kill the process after 5 mins since its still trying to grab the result). The data I'm trying to bring back has over 30million rows which is why I want to use MySql ResultSet streaming approaching.

I did some investigation, but couldn't find any information on what type of queries MySql ResultSet streaming is suppose to support. There docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html doesn't provide any information on this.

Comment: Are you sure the query can be executed in 5 minutes?

Comment: @kayaman The way the streaming works is row by row. I should be getting a response back that contains one record from the
` rs = statement.executeQuery(myComplexQuery)`

And then when I call "rs.next" that will stream the next row until "rs.next == false".

Comment: It's not as simple as that. While something as simple as `SELECT * FROM Foo` doesn't need to do anything special before starting to return rows, anything more complex needs to first build the results before it can start streaming it. Queries that take long will still take long. Use `EXPLAIN` to see how the query performs and optimize it if necessary. Streaming results is not magic, it's just a way to avoid excess use of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streaming happens when the results are ready to be transferred. If you have a complex query it can still take minutes before the first row can be streamed.

Streaming is advantageous because it allows you to use less memory for large result sets. From a speed point of view it's basically always better to read all the results into memory before processing them.

Comment: You are correct, turns out the underlying issue was my query.